# PathPrefixStrip is ignored on ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, traefik-ingress

**Traefik version 2.5.6**

I have the following ingress settings:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
  traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /users
  traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: PathPrefixStrip

  name: users
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dev.[REDUCTED]
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: users-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /users
        pathType: Prefix
```

But when I call:

```
curl -i http://dev.[REDUCTED]/users/THIS-SHOUD-BE-ROOT
```

I get in the pod, serving the service:

```
error: GET /users/THIS-SHOUD-BE-ROOT 404
```

What can be the reason for that?

Comment: what is `THIS-SHOUD-BE-ROOT`. It's not clear for me what is your expected result. And your yaml looks incorrect, where have you found this? You can to refer to this link: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/basics/#path-matcher-usage-guidelines and the example there

Comment: replace it with abcd. This is just a string. Doesn't matter what it is.
The example that you have provided is for v1.7. It doesn't work on Traefik 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Traefik Routers](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.5/user-guides/crd-acme/#traefik-routers) as in the example below:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: users
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
  - match: Host(`dev.[REDUCTED]`) && PathPrefix(`/users`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: users-service
      port: 80
```

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Yes. It works. Seems like Traefik 2.x does everything to enforce people migrate from Ingress to IngressRoute. I have  upvoted and accepted this as a solution, even though this is a workaround.